# If one of the attribute of my class is a dictionary, how to define the set property for it?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, properties, attributes

I have an issue with a class that I built. This class has many attributes, one of them is a dictionary. The reason why I turned to having a dictionary, is that I want to add parameters to my class depending on the situation, and I don't know a better way. I know there is the possibility to create new attributes of the class on the fly with "setattr", but I read that it was not necessarily a good practice.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, params_dict={"p1": 1, "p2":-0.136}):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.params_dict = params_dict
    
myobject = MyClass(a=0, b=4, params_dict={"p1": 1, "p2":-0.136, "p3":89})
```

But now I am stuck because I would like to define properties for params_dict. It works for the getter, but not for the setter:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, params_dict={"p1": 1, "p2":-0.136}):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self._params_dict = params_dict

    def _get_params_dict(self):
        return self._params_dict
    def _set_params_dict(self, params_dict):
        # print("Hello")
    params_dict = property(_get_params_dict, _set_params_dict)

myobject = MyClass(a=0, b=4, params_dict={"p1": 1, "p2":-0.136, "p3":89})
print(myobject.params_dict["p1"]) # returns "1", so that is fine
myobject.params_dict["p2"] = 10 # this modifies the dictionary myobject.params_dict but do not print "Hello"
```

The way I understand it is that the setter is not called because I do not change the dictionary, I am just modifying one of its keys. But how to make it work when I just change one of its keys?

I am very open to smarter solutions to add attributes on the fly if you think there is another way to go around that issue and still set properties there.

Thank you for your help!

---

Edit: I understand now that when I do myobject.params_dict["p2"] = 10, the getter is called, not the setter, as it does not recognize ["p2"] as a modification of params_dict.

Comment: If you want to access and set it with `myobject.params_dict["p1"]` why do you need the property? Why not just directly access the dictionary? i.e: `self.params_dict = params_dict`

Comment: Yes, it is because I want to trigger a method inside the class when the dictionary is modified, and forbid to add more keys after the construction of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in your code here `myobject.params_dict["p2"] = 10` is:

You access a property `params_dict` which returned `_params_dict` of the instance... **then** you assign `10` to its item `p2`. The setter never comes to play and also could not... not like this. If you wanted to use a property setter, you could:

```
class MyClass:
   ...
    def _set_params_dict(self, params_dict):
        self._params_dict.update(params_dict)

...
myobject.params_dict = {"p2": 10}
```

Setter which updates the dict is used, when you assign to the property.

This should explain what went down and why. How to do this "properly"... depends on what exactly are you after.

---

Side note: Using this:

```
def __init__(self, a, b, params_dict={"p1": 1, "p2":-0.136})
    self._params_dict = params_dict
```

Means that when your class is created a dictionary object is created and assigned as default parameter for the constructor... which is then assigned to an attribute of the instance.

In turn this implies, all instances where default `params_dict` is used (no value was supplied) share the same one dictionary object for `_params_dict`.

---

To address your comment: it's not a matter of (my) opinion. You can get exactly the interface usable the way you've suggested having custom action performed when setting an item, but you would have to modify the `_params_dict` type to do that, e.g.:

```
class ParamsDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value, /):
        print(f"Special action setting {key}")
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, params_dict=(("p1", 1), ("p2", -0.136))):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.params_dict = ParamsDict(params_dict)

myobject = MyClass(a=0, b=4, params_dict={"p1": 1, "p2":-0.136, "p3":89})
myobject.params_dict["p2"] = 20
```

You could also consider just exposing items of `params_dict` attribute as items of `MyClass` if that makes sense for your use case:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, params_dict=None):
        if params_dict is None:
            param_dict = {"p1": 1, "p2": -0.136}
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.params_dict = params_dict

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.params_dict[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f"Special action setting {key}")
        self.params_dict[key] = value

myobject = MyClass(a=0, b=4, params_dict={"p1": 1, "p2":-0.136, "p3":89})
myobject["p2"] = 20
print(myobject["p2"])
```

But without much more context and understanding why (where is all this heading) by far the easiest (and likely cleanest) solution would often be to not bother with either of the above and just define a method to do do this - set a parameter value and perform whatever other operations you need, e.g.:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, params_dict=None):
        if params_dict is None:
            param_dict = {"p1": 1, "p2": -0.136}
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.params_dict = params_dict

    def set_param(self, key, value):
        print(f"Special action setting {key}")
        self.params_dict[key] = value

myobject = MyClass(a=0, b=4, params_dict={"p1": 1, "p2":-0.136, "p3":89})
myobject.set_param("p2", 20)
print(myobject.params_dict["p2"])
```

---

Update for the next comment: Well, you need to also make `ParamDict` instance aware of `MyClass` instance that contains it (or a method thereof it needs to call), e.g.:

```
class ParamsDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, container, *args, **kwargs):
        self._setparam_callback = container.setparam_callback
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value, /):
        self._setparam_callback(key, value)
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, params_dict=(("p1", 1), ("p2", -0.136))):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.params_dict = ParamsDict(self, params_dict)

    def setparam_callback(self, key, value):
        print(f"Special action setting {key} to {value}")

myobject = MyClass(a=0, b=4, params_dict={"p1": 1, "p2":-0.136, "p3":89})
myobject.params_dict["p2"] = 20
```

If you want to hold set of key/value pairs (and you may not know what they are up front), `dict` sounds like just a type for the job. I suspect you may be over-complicating things, simple:

```
myobject.set_param("p2", 20)
myobject.get_param("p2")
```

May look trivial(?), but gets the job done. It's also plenty obvious, which is generally a good thing.

Properties are not really going to help you all that much with what you've described. Somewhat similar appearance to expose data and "dynamically" handle access to attributes can be achieved by overloading **getattr** (and **setattr** for assignment), but again, simple is generally good.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. This update() is neat, I did not know. But so you think there is no way to update a value in the dictionary the way I wrote it?  myobject.params_dict["p2"] = 10. Because I would need it to be as simple as possible for the user. I need to trigger a certain method in the setter when a value of the dictionary is changed, that is why i am bumping my head against the wall. And then I need to be able to do a for loop on these special "attributes" (keys of the dictionary) within the class.

Comment: Thank you for this edit. I like the ParamDict Class option, the only thing is that I need to trigger a method in MyClass when params_dict is modified, therefore having the property in ParamDict does not work fully for me. Your last option with the method "set_param" is indeed the cleanest, but how do I prevent the user from modifying it with simply with myobject["p2"] = 20?

Comment: I am sorry if all this looks like I am not giving enough info to fully view what I am looking for. I tried to simplify as much as possible (maybe too much) what I needed, which is basically: add parameters on the fly to my class only when I create the object (I don't know if a dictionary is the best), and trigger actions when these parameters are modified (which I thought should be through a property on the dictionary that carries these parameters). The other option would be to create attributes on the fly, that I know how to do, but how to create properties on the fly for each of them?

Comment: Wonderful Ondrej, thank you so much for your big help! I like also your recommendations regarding good practices, that is exactly what I like to learn.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think `setattr` is better than this approach, you would avoid having this extra-layer in between.

2) I would write it:

```
def set_parameter(self, key, value):
   print("Hello") # hi !
   self._params_dict[key] = value
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The 2) does not work. I guess it is because the setter is not called when I do myobject.params_dict["p2"] = 10. Regarding the 1), I could I guess, but then I would need properties for each separate attributes added on the fly, is it possible to do that? What I don't like with this 1) is that I get warnings from my text editor telling me that this attribute does not exist until I run the code.